# How to measure the similarity between two weighted graphs？

Tags: graph-theory, network, adjacency-matrix

I have two undirected graph networks and each edge of these networks are weighted through the Pearson Correlation Coefficient values.(Both of these networks have same nodes) I would like to quantify the difference (or change) between these two graph networks (actually they are two matrices)

Do you know how to solve this problem? Thx：)

Comment: Do you have an edge between any pair of nodes or just between some of the nodes?

Comment: @quarague just between some nodes, not all of them

Comment: I think the answer here strongly depends on what you want this difference to measure. You could do something like summing up the absolute values of the differences between edge pair or similar. But whether this is useful depends on the application you have in mind.

Comment: @quarague I just want to quantify the changes in the weights of the two networks.